# React, React Redux, Redux Form type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this problem and can't solve it.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {RenderField} from 'modules/shared/components/RenderField';


class Register extends React.Component {
    handleFormSubmit(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
    render() {
        const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="form-popup">
                <div className="form-popup-content">
                    <h4 className="popup-title">Daftar Baru</h4>

                    <hr className="line-separator"/>

                    <form id="register-form" name="registerForm" method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>

                        <Field name="name" type="text" component={RenderField} label="Name"/>

                        <button type="submit" id="register-button" className="button mid dark ladda-button"
                                data-style="expand-right">
                            Register
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return state;
}

Register = reduxForm({
    form: 'registerForm',
})(Register);
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null))(Register);
```

Compile and I got this error:

`Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Register)` should be after `connect()`.

Change

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null))(Register);
```

to

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Register));
```

Comment: OMG! silly me not realize that!. Thanks queen of pain :D

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to see there are Dota players on StackOverflow 